# Line number of SyntaxError in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, v8

I have some code that uses `vm` module and `runInNewContext` function and executes dynamically generated JavaScript code. Basically a safer option of `eval`.

The code (variable `code`) can possibly contain syntax errors, so I would like to catch them and print some useful information.

```
try {
    vm.runInNewContext(code, sandbox, filename);
}
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) { // always false
        console.log(e.toString()); // "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||" for example
        console.log(e.line); // how to get the line number?
    }
}
```

I'd like to print the number of the line with the syntax error, but I have two problems:

- I don't know how to recognize whether the exception is `SyntaxError` or something else. `instaceof` doesn't work (update - I can use `e.name === "SyntaxError"`).
- Even if I was able to recognize it, how could I get the line number? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I can get some information from `e.stack` - however, the topmost call in the stack trace is `runInNewContext` (with its line number), but I still can't find the line number inside `code`, which caused the exception (`SyntaxError`).

Comment: Unfortunately, the information you are looking for cannot currently be obtained from the SyntaxError object: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2589

Answer (score 4):

use a try/catch

store the stack in a global variable

log the sandbox

```
var util = require('util');
var vm = require('vm');
var sandbox = {e:null};
var src = 'try{count += 1;}catch(err) {e=err.stack}';

vm.runInNewContext(src , sandbox, 'myfile.vm');
console.log(util.inspect(sandbox));
```

this will log:

> { e: 'ReferenceError: count is not defined\n    at myfile.vm:1:13\n
>   ...

now you can see that the error occurs at line 1, character 13 of myfile.vm
this will still require you to place some try/cathc blocks at various places
but at least you can get feedback now

### EDIT:

Adding a method to detect Syntax errors from within your running code

```
var acorn = require('acorn');
var src = "try{\n"+
    "   {" +
    "       count += 1;\n"+
    "   }catch(err) {\n" +
    "       e=err.stack\n" +
    "}";

var result = acorn.parse(src);
```

doing this will result in a thrown Exception with 
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:4)"
eg. line 3, character 4 is the unexpected token, (the extra { that shouldnt be there)

Comment: any error youll be able to catch really, just place the try/catch at strategic places

Comment: also you can run the file trough some tools like jslint, and set the 'use strict' directive globally for the file, to catch some errors outside of the vm

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, this cannot catch SyntaxError.

Comment: @MartinMajer ah syntaxerrors, then why should this have to catch that, you ahv eth file, contents, and you know its javascript. Open a browser and load the file, include the file with node require, use js lint, all of these will tell you the error, line and character location

Comment: The source code is dynamically generated (compiled from a template file to JavaScript), so I can't do this.

Comment: @MartinMajer I dont understand why if you have the source (either as string of file) can you not get the source and run in trough acorn, try/catch the parse and youll have the location of the syntax error

Comment: @MartinMajer btw. see the edit, i added the code how you can get the location of the SyntaxError

Comment: Thanks. Acorn seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

1) Use `if (e.name === "SyntaxError")`.

2) All data associated with the error is kept in `e.stack`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, `e.stack` contains only the line number of the `vm.runInNewContext` call (not the line number in the executed code).

Comment: @MartinMajer You can try using `util.inspect(e);` ( http://nodejs.org/api/util.html ) however I doubt you'll be able to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit (very) old, you can use the [`stackedy` module](https://github.com/substack/node-stackedy), which can help you manipulate stack traces. It isn't the perfect solution though, as the line number displayed is the line number inside the function call, and not the line number in the source file.

In particular, look at the [simple example](https://github.com/substack/node-stackedy/tree/master/example/simple):

*index.js*

```
var stackedy = require('stackedy');
var fs = require('fs');

var src = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/src.js');
var stack = stackedy(src, { filename : 'stax.js' }).run();

stack.on('error', function (err, c) {
    stack.stop();
    console.log('Error: ' + err);

    var cur = c.current;
    console.log('  in ' + cur.filename + ' at line ' + cur.start.line);

    c.stack.forEach(function (s) {
        console.log('  in ' + s.filename + ', '
            + s.functionName + '() at line ' + s.start.line
        );
    });
});
```

*src.js*

```
function f () { g() }
function g () { h() }
function h () { throw new SyntaxError('woops') }

f();
```

*Output:*

```
~/tmp ❯❯❯ node index.js
Error: SyntaxError: woops
  in stax.js at line 2
  in stax.js, h() at line 1
  in stax.js, g() at line 0
  in stax.js, f() at line 4
```

As noted in the comments, you can use `err.name === 'SyntaxError'` to check for the error type.

Answer (score 0):

For *nix:

`if (err) console.log(err.stack.split('\n')[1]);`

It will log second line of stacktrace, the point where the error occured.

Windows or mac can require other split symbol (depends on system line endings)